# Java ZipCoder Exception

Tags: java, nio, java-11

I am creating a file manager with Java (Windows only for now). The user can navigate inside zip-files as they can into local folders, with the help of NIO & ZipFileSystem.

Everything works fine -- with the exception of certain files inside zips that contain some "special" characters - for example a file named: GlkEspañol.dll.

If I use the ZipFileSystem's default encoding (UTF-8) - I get this exception for zip-files that contain files with these special characters, at least in some cases:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED[1]
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:90)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipCoder$UTF8.toString(ZipCoder.java:64)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.getString(ZipFileSystem.java:938)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.toString(ZipPath.java:603)
```

As a result, I saw no other option than to fallback to Windows-1252 encoding for the ZipFileSystem. Now I get no exceptions, but the filenames look like garbage.

I tested this same zip-file with several other file managers (not Java-based though), and they display the files just fine.

Anyone else encountered this same issue? I'm still not sure if this is a Java bug or what. Is there anything better I can do about it, than to fallback to Windows-1252?

Comment: Then the zip was not created with encoding UTF-8 obviously? Since 2007 the standard is to use UTF-8 for file names, but Windows poses its own "standard" perhaps. Java should almost automatically create zip files with UTF-8 names.

Comment: Can you provide some code as an example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'll see if I'll create an mcve a bit later with the zip-file in question. But, that exception is thrown everytime I simply call `(Zip)Path.getFileName().toString()`.